# css hover,active effect not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, computer-science

I can't figure out why default color for "a"  element is set to #2bb673,when it's must be #222. What did i do wrong? 
Also i'm using bootstrap

```
    <div class="our-work">
        <a href="#our-work" class="our-work">Our Work</a>
     </div>
```

CSS

```
 .our-work a {
      color:#222;
    }

.our-work a:link {text-decoration: none; color: #2bb673;}
.our-work a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #2bb673 ;}
.our-work a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #2bb673;}
.our-work a:active {text-decoration: none; color: #2bb673;}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kani339/8h98f84k/)

Comment: your fiddle link contains nothing

Comment: [FTFY](http://jsfiddle.net/8h98f84k/1/)

Comment: `a:link { }` overrides `a { }`. Also, replace your repeating rules by a comma separated selector: `.our-work a:visited, .our-work a:hover, .our-work a:active { }`

Comment: you've mentioned in some comments that the problem is the blue color that shows up by default for visited links.  This is not indicated in your question.  I suggest another edit so that you start getting the answers you really want

Comment: @ Andrea Jessup i figured out, i added focus instead visited and it worked

Comment: glad you've got a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question, this will fix it:

```
.our-work a:link {text-decoration: none; color: #222;}
.our-work a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #2bb673 ;}
.our-work a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #2bb673;}
.our-work a:active {text-decoration: none; color: #2bb673;}
```

`a:link` is going to override `a`, so you need to put the #222 color in there.

However, remember that you have `a:visited` pseudo-class color set to the green, so if you have visited that link (while testing?), it will still show as green even if you've fixed the css to show the #222 color on an unvisited link.

Solutions:

1. Change both `a:link` and `a:visited` to #222
2. Change each of the 4 states to a different color while figuring this out so you can see which pseudo-class is actually affecting the `a` element. Then if you still can't figure it out, update your question with a more detailed description of the actual results you need.

Edit: original question didn't specify OP is using bootstrap.  This solution will work with clean CSS, but does not get rid of the blue "visited" state that happens by default with bootstrap.

Comment: if i do so it's works with clean css, but i'm using also bootstrap and visited link color is dark blue,and i need to fix it

Comment: I strongly suggest you add the fact that this is Bootstrap to your question - that definitely makes a difference as to what will solve your problem!!

Answer (score 3):

`.our-work a {}` applies to all states, and then you go and specify each state this way:

```
.our-work a:link {text-decoration: none; color: #2bb673;}
```

`a:link` overrides the default state you specified earlier.

So just remove the `a:link` style, or change it to `#222`, as your default.

Comment: ...and most likely would also override just by being more specific, which takes precedence, no matter the order.

Comment: @wwwmarty didn't helped,

Comment: that should work. are you able to see the change if you remove the visited styles?

Comment: @cocoa if i remove visited, this works, but as i'm using bootstrap,when link is visited it's showing dark blue color, that's the problem